# how to save ints in a string to elements in array

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, ifstream

What im trying to achieve is to read in data from a `.txt` file line by line, using `getline()`, and save it as a string to the variable `inVal`. I then want to save each individual number that is in the string to an individual element in the objects array by passing it to the member function `ArrayBag.add(value)`. So far I've been able to read in data to `inVal` fine but nothing I've tried has been able to convert and save the numbers in the string, including the code below after `getline()`. Please any guidance or tips would be much appreciated.

the `.txt` file looks like this:

```
 3  4  5  7  5 16 7 12 11 12  3  9  9  8  1 12
15  4  3  6 1 12  3 12 7  8 19  9 11 12  8  5 -4  -100
```

My code that ive written so far is like this:

```
void readInv(ArrayBag &ArrayBag1, ArrayBag &ArrayBag2) {
    //ArrayBag1 and ArrayBag2 are objects of class ArrayBag

    std::string inVal;
    //value to hold each line in file

    std::ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open("setInventory.txt");    //"setInventory.txt" is the txt file being read from.

    if (readFile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "File is being read." << std::endl;

        while(!readFile.eof()) {
            getline(readFile, inVal);

            for(int i = 0; i < inVal.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << inVal[i] << std::endl;

                ArrayBag1.add(inVal[i] - '0');
                //ArrayBag1.add() is the public member function used to add the
                //passing value to the private member array.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off topic (but will solve a bug that's coming soon): [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line). Specifically answer 1 option 2.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use `std::vector` for this? Vectors are much better than arrays.

Comment: Check out top answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/most-elegant-way-to-split-a-string

Comment: @Sailanarmo The assignment prohibits the use of vectors, the class ArrayBag works like a custom vector though so were supposed to use that.

Comment: Here you can find very good tips about splitting a string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/most-elegant-way-to-split-a-string

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use the [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/)

```
  stringstream ss{readFile};
  while(ss)
 {
   //doing something
   int a;
   ss>>a;
  ArrayBag1.add(a);
 }
```